# Python and Asterisk

Tags: python, asterisk

Has anyone successfully used a Python API to connect to Asterisk AMI? Maybe Starpy or py-asterisk, or even FATS?

If so can you please display examples or point to a link?

There seems to be very little documentation regarding the Python APIs.

Answer (score 5):

i am successfully using https://github.com/al-the-x/pyst for years

see usage example in the doc block here - https://github.com/al-the-x/pyst/blob/master/asterisk/manager.py

Answer (score 3):

Did you check/try [Pyst](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst/)?

Comment: Just tried it out. Works great. Only problem the documentation is in the docstring. But so far so good :)

Answer (score 3):

Use pyst2, it's a fork of pyst. Last is not develops any more. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyst2/0.4

Answer (score 2):

[pyst on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst/) seems to be alive again, and I'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

Use pyst. Download it from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyst/)

Now just extract the tar file, go to the directory of pyst through terminal and enter following commands.

```
python setup.py install
```

Now, in your python script add

```
from asterisk.agi import *
```

Now you are all set to use asterisk with python.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote panoramisk which is python3 only (old releases can work with python2.7)

https://github.com/gawel/panoramisk